# Generic type mismatch while using a Collector returned by the method - Java 17

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, collectors, java-17

I was experimenting with `records` and *streams*.

I've created these *records* to count the number of letters in a text.

```
record Letter(int code) {
    Letter(int code) {
        this.code = Character.toLowerCase(code);
    }
}

record LetterCount(long count) implements Comparable<LetterCount> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(LetterCount other) {
        return Long.compare(this.count, other.count);
    }

    static Collector<Letter, Object, LetterCount> countingLetters() {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.<Letter>counting(), 
            LetterCount::new);
    }
}
```

And here is the snippet where they're used:

```
final var countedChars = text.chars()
    .mapToObj(Letter::new)
    .collect(
        groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
            LetterCount.countingLetters()                      // compilation error
            // collectingAndThen(counting(), LetterCount::new) // this line doesn't produce error
        ));
```

The snippet shown above doesn't produce error if I comment out `collectingAndThen()` to be used as the downstream collector within the `groupingBy()`.

However, the compiler gets lost when I'm trying to use `LetterCount.countingLetters()` as the downstream collector.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        Collector cannot be resolved to a type
        Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Letter,capture#17-of ?,LetterCount> to Collector<Letter,Object,LetterCount>
        The method countingLetters() from the type LetterCount refers to the missing type Collector
        The method entrySet() is undefined for the type Object
```

Comment: By the way, to make your code more robust, call `String#codePoints` rather than `String#chars`. The `char` type is legacy, physically incapable of representing most characters. Your code may fail with characters from outside the [BMP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interface [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) has the following declaration:

```
public interface Collector<T,​A,​R>
```

Where the second generic type parameter `A` denotes the type of the *mutable container* which is used internally to accumulate the results of the reduction. This type is usually hidden by the implementations.

Your method `countingLetters()` declares the return type as follows:

```
Collector<Letter, Object, LetterCount>
```

And that implies the type of the *mutable container* of the collector returned by this method is expected to be an `Object`.

*Reminder:* generics are **invariant**, i.e. if you've said `Object` you have to provide only `Object` (not it's subtype, not *unknown type* `?`, only the `Object` type itself).

And that is incorrect for several reasons:

- All *collectors* built-in in the JDK are hiding their types of mutable containers. Collector `conting` that you are using in your code declares to return `Collector<T,?,Long>`. Under the hood, it makes use of `summingLong`, which in turn returns `Collector<T,?,Long>` although it internally utilizes `long[]` as a *container*. That is because it doesn't make sense to expose these implementation details. And as a consequence, generic parameters of the return type you've declared doesn't conform to the generic parameters of the *collector* that you are returning. I.e. since you are given an unknown type `?`, you can't declare to return an `Object`.
- Even if you wouldn't use built-in collectors, but your own *custom collector* instead, it still will not be a very bright idea to expose the *actual type* of its *container*. Simply because sometime in the future, you might want to change it.
- `Object` class is immutable, hence it's fruitless to use it as a container type (*if you would try to implement a custom collector*) because it is not capable to accumulate data.

---

**The bottom line:** the second generic parameter in the *collector* returned by the `countingLetters()` method isn't correct.

To fix it, you have to change the type of the *mutable container* to be either:

- an unknown type `?` which encompasses all possible types, i.e. expected that provided collector may have a *mutable container* of any type (and that's how all collectors in the JDK have been declared);
- or to an upper bounded wildcard `? extends Object` (which is basically a more verbose way to describe the *unknown type*).

```
public static Collector<Letter, ?, LetterCount> countingLetters()
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I changed the signature as per your suggestion: `public static Collector<Letter, ?, LetterCount> countingLetters()`. Unfortunately, it didn't work. This is the error now: 
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Letter,capture#17-of ?,LetterCount> to Collector<Letter,?,LetterCount>`

Comment: @dbaltor That is the same code that I'm running on my machine [*jdoodle.com/ia/q05*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/q05) (you can execute it online).

Comment: `?` and `? extends Object` are identical - just as a type variable `T` and `T extends Object` are equivalent.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Sure, unbounded wild card is the same as `? extends Object` and I didn't tell that they are different. I've mentioned that a parameter can be defined this way because it's more expressive, and clear that not strictly `Object` is expected (*like in the OP's code*) but something that encompass all possible subtypes of `Object` and `Object` itself. In regard to bounded parameter (`T extends Object`) it has *different purpose than wild card* `?`, and it's *not applicable* in this method.

Comment: Yeah - my point is: ` extends Object` can be omitted. Nothing more.

Comment: Hey @AlexanderIvanchenko. Happy new year! I was reading this question again and I had accepted your answer and upvoted it back in the day. However just realised I forgot to say I followed your advice on using Intellij since then. It solved the error I was getting with your code in VS code. Thanks for the answer and advice. Much appreciated.